# How to store the id of document inside same doc in flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to store the id of a document inside the same doc in flutter firestore

[image]
[image]

I am getting the recipe id null

```
Future updateRecipeData(RecipeModel recipeModel) async {
    await recipeDataCollection.doc().set({
      rRecipeTitle: recipeModel.title,
      rRecipeBundleName: recipeModel.recipeBundleName,
      rCookingTime: recipeModel.cookingTime,
      rDateTime: recipeModel.dateTime,
      rImgPath: recipeModel.imgPath,
      rIngredients: recipeModel.ingredients,
      rNumOfLikes: recipeModel.numOfLikes,
      rPreparation: recipeModel.preparation,
      rServings: recipeModel.servings,
    });
    print('Data TRANSFORMED');
  }

  List<RecipeModel> getRecipes(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return RecipeModel(
        title: doc.data()[rRecipeTitle],
        cookingTime: doc.data()[rCookingTime],
        imgPath: doc.data()[rImgPath],
        ingredients: List.from(doc.data()[rIngredients]),
        preparation: List.from(doc.data()[rPreparation]),
        numOfLikes: doc.data()[rNumOfLikes],
        dateTime: doc.data()[rDateTime],
        servings: doc.data()[rServings],
        recipeBundleName: doc.data()[rRecipeBundleName],
        recipeId: doc.id,
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<RecipeModel>> get recipeData {
    return recipeDataCollection.snapshots().map(getRecipes);
  }
```

This is the code I want to the doc id store it inside recipeid.

RECIPE MODEL CODE

```
class RecipeModel {
  String title, imgPath, recipeBundleName, recipeId;
  String cookingTime, servings;
  int numOfLikes;
  String dateTime;
  List<String> ingredients, preparation;

  RecipeModel({
    this.title,
    this.cookingTime,
    this.imgPath,
    this.recipeBundleName,
    this.servings,
    this.numOfLikes,
    this.dateTime,
    this.ingredients,
    this.preparation,
    this.recipeId,
  });
}
```

I shared the recipe model and has recipeId to store the id of the doc inside same doc .

Comment: "How to store the id of a document inside the same doc in flutter firestore" => Do you really want to store the document ID **as a field in the document**, or you just have problem getting the doc ID in `getRecipes()`? In addition can you share the code of `RecipeModel`?

Comment: I want to store it inside the doc or if there is a way to stream the doc id

Comment: What do you get when you do `return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {print(doc.id); return RecipeModel();...`? In other word can you check that you get the correct ids in the map?

Comment: I get the id is null

Comment: That's quite surprising, because a `QueryDocumentSnapshot` does have an `id` property... Do you correctly get the other values, e.g. `title`?

Comment: Can I get this id using stream builder ?!

Comment: Yes, since you pass a `QuerySnapshot` to the builder. But if you have a problem with your current code, you'll probably have the same with a `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: Can you please write the code in answer box

Comment: I would suggest that you try to write the code yourself, based on the example in the documentation: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#realtime-changes. I'll be happy to look at any problem you may encounter. Don't forget to debug as much as you can if you get problems.

Comment: I edit my question can you see the code I want the id from stream builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you share the codes? In order to print the id of the same document, you need to create the id in the codes and send it while setting or updating it.

answer:

```
String docId = recipeDataCollection.doc().id; // id create await 

recipeDataCollection.doc(docId).set({ 
docId: docId, // this 
rRecipeTitle: recipeModel.title, 
rRecipeBundleName: recipeModel.recipeBundleName, 
rCookingTime: recipeModel.cookingTime, 
rDateTime: recipeModel.dateTime, 
rImgPath: recipeModel.imgPath, 
rIngredients: recipeModel.ingredients, 
rNumOfLikes: recipeModel.numOfLikes, 
rPreparation: recipeModel.preparation, 
rServings: recipeModel.servings, 
});
```

Comment: I added the code

Comment: can you tell me how to create the id in the codes and send it while setting or updating it.

Comment: String docId = recipeDataCollection.doc().id; // id create
await recipeDataCollection.doc(docId).set({

      docId: docId, // this     

      rRecipeTitle: recipeModel.title,
      rRecipeBundleName: recipeModel.recipeBundleName,
      rCookingTime: recipeModel.cookingTime,
      rDateTime: recipeModel.dateTime,
      rImgPath: recipeModel.imgPath,
      rIngredients: recipeModel.ingredients,
      rNumOfLikes: recipeModel.numOfLikes,
      rPreparation: recipeModel.preparation,
      rServings: recipeModel.servings,
    });